# How exactly does styled-components syntax work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I was looking at styled-components and I saw this syntax:

```js
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;
```

I can't understand what is going on under the hood and what property is actually applied to the `styled` object.
Is there anyone that can explain to me how this code even runs?

Comment: [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

This is basically a function, but you can run it without `()`

```js
const styled = data => {
  return data + ' JavaScript';
};

const data = styled `I love`;

console.log(data);
```

Examples with built-in functions:

```js
console.log('a b c'.split ` `)
console.log(Object.entries `abc`)
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat `abc`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create styled h1 element, for example in Header component :

```js
    const Title = styled.h1`
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
    `;
```

You use it like a `<h1>` tag but with custom name:

```js
    <Title>My portfolio</Title>
```

You finally get the static hash class name `sc-<hashedStringName>` and one is dynamic class:

```
  <h1 class="sc-gsnERi fiwDZi">My portfolio</h1>
```

So styled-components:

- generate static class name
- generate dynamic class name

Answer (score 0):

This basically allows you to create Custom Tag in JSX.
You can also pass props to the styling properties in styled-components.

If you have this jsx:

```
<Title>This is Custom H1</Title>

const Title = styled.h1`
  color: red;
`
```

It will render HTML like this:

```
<h1 class="someRandomAlphabet">This is Custom H1</h1>
```

where the class of **h1** tag will have these properties:

```
.someRandomAlphabet{
  color: red;
}
```